# Passing a string from Android to JS in a WebView via @JavascriptInterface

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

Here is my Javascript interface:

```
class WebAppInterface(val context: Context){

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun provideAString():String{
        println("executed from js")
        println("this is text")
        return "this is text"
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun printTheString(s:String){
        println(s)
    }
}
```

Here's how I add it to the WebView:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "Android")
```

Here's how I call the two functions from JS:

```
function StringFromAndroid(){
    var string=Android.provideAString();
}

...
...

var currentString=new StringFromAndroid();
Android.printTheString(currentString.string);
```

Here are the print lines:

```
I/System.out: executed from js  
I/System.out: this is text
I/System.out: undefined
```

Expected behavior:

Print lines 1 and 2 demonstrate that `provideAString()` is being called correctly from JS. Print line 3 shows that `printTheString(s)` is being called correctly from JS, but that the value of `currentString.string` inside the WebView is "undefined". The expected behavior is that when `var currentString=new StringFromAndroid();` forces a call to `Android.provideAString();` via the line `var string=Android.provideAString();`, that call would return the string "this is text" and set `var string` to have that value so that resultingly, `currentString.string` would be "this is text" instead of "undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the value of `Android.provideAString();` to `this`:

```
function StringFromAndroid() {
    this.string = Android.provideAString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only work with js once every few months so I always have to relearn how properties work inside "classes". I'll leave the question up anyway.

Comment: ...on the basis that the title is accurate and my template along with your answer gives a searcher sufficient material to implement this kind of workflow.